# What driver do I need for a PCI Simple Communications Controller in Lenovo T400?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, thinkpad

I installed Windows 7 on a Lenovo T400 laptop. In the Device Manager, the only piece of unrecognized hardware is a "PCI Simple Communications Controller". Does anybody know what driver I need for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also just realized I have the same problem on my T400 running Windows 7 x64, luckily I found a solution.  Looks like those devices are related to the Intel Advanced Management Technology in the BIOS.

The driver can be found on the [IBM support website](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-70313).

[Here is a link](http://blog.mobile01.com/merlin/print/984) to a blog that has a bit of an explanation.

And just for some additional info, [here is the entire driver listing](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?sitestyle=lenovo&lndocid=MIGR-72858) for the T400

Comment: Confirmed. The unknown "PCI Simple Communications Controller" ended up being the "Management Engine Interface" driver downloadable from the Lenovo site

Answer (score 1):

a "PCI Simple Communications Controller" is usually an analog 56k modem.